# Scheme - Expects a non-empty list

Tags: list, scheme, racket, empty-list

For reference I am programming with `Scheme` using `DrRacket`.

When I run the program I get the following error message:

```
check-expect encountered the following error instead of the expected value, 
(list false true true true). 
   :: first: expects a non-empty list; given: string?
```

I am not sure what the issue is, as it seems the code should run fine.

```
;; Signature: mymap: (x -> y) listofX -> listofY
;; Purpose: Consumes a function from X –> Y, and a list of X; returns a list of Y;
;;          by applying the function to each item in the list of X.

(define (mymap g alist)
  (cond
    [(empty? alist) empty]
    [else
     (cons (g (first alist))
           (mymap (rest alist) g))]
    )
  )

;; define 2 other functions using mymap and write
;; one check-expect for each of these functions

(check-expect (mymap string? (list 1 "ab" "abc" "")) (list false true true true))
(check-expect (mymap sqr (list 1 0 -3 4 -5)) (list 1 0 9 16 25))

(define (C2F c)
  (+ (* 9/5 c) 32))

(define (cf* alist)
  (mymap alist C2F))

(check-expect (mymap C2F (list 100 0 -40)) (list 212 32 -40))
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You inverted the parameters in your recursive call to `mymap`, use:

```
      (mymap g (rest alist)))]
```

instead of

```
      (mymap (rest alist) g))]
```

Comment: @BBladem83: also, once you realize the real problem, go back and re-read the error message again.  See if you understand what the error message was trying to say.  This will help in the future, because you will certainly repeat these kind of mistakes from time to time.  I know that I do.  :P  If you're running in DrRacket, clicking on the error message should bring your cursor to the offending line.